# Control of queued connections of a python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm beginner in python sockets.
I'm programming a TCP socket that receives data from the same client. The problem is that I don't have control of the client and it sends data constantly, but I want to receive the first connection and ignore the queued connections that my socket received during a period of time. After that period, my socket starts receiving connections again.

I have coded this:

```
socket_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_tcp.bind((host, port)) 
socket_tcp.listen(5) 

count = 0
while True:
    conn, addr = socket_tcp.accept()
    print('successful connection')
    file = r'C:\Users\folder' + str(count) + '.json'
    count += 1
    with open(file, "wb") as f:        
        chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

        while chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

    conn.close()
```

Is Python’s select() function a possible way?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of python socket [socket.listen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen)
you can set the value to 0 as follows:

```
socket_tcp.listen(0)
```

this will drop all new connections if your server socket already has an established connection, and when the connection is closed your server socket will start accepting connections again.